# Is there a better way to case match dirty characters?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

I'm writing an iPhone application with Swift 2.0, and I don't want people to be able to enter dirty characters into the textfield. I'm trying to wrap this code into a function and return a bool to use later in the application. So far, the code does what it's supposed to do in the playground without being wrapped in a function. However, when I wrap it in a function the playground doesn't like the code. Is there an easier way to do what I'm doing?

I'm new to Swift 2.0, have read the programming guide, but am not sure how to go about finding functions I need in the SDK/API. I've read Apple's documentation in the past, but I haven't understood how to use it. I can't seem to ever find the information I'm looking for in it.

There has got to be a way to keep from making hundreds of passes.

I would also like to see how to use return values later too. The programming guide doesn't give a good real world example.

This is my first language.

```
    var randomText: String = "D*rtyCh4ract3rs!#"

    var isCleanText:Bool = true

    let dirtyCharacters: String = "~`!@#$%^&*()_+=-{}[]|;\'<>,./?1234567890"

    var dirtyStringArray = [String]()

    var boolCountArray = [Bool]()

    for singleCharacter in dirtyCharacters.characters {

        dirtyStringArray.append("\(singleCharacter)")

        for testCase in dirtyStringArray {

        if (randomText as NSString).containsString(testCase).boolValue {

            boolCountArray.append((randomText as NSString).containsString(testCase).boolValue)

            if boolCountArray.count > 0 {

                isCleanText = false

                print(boolCountArray)

                break

            } else {

                isCleanText = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

print(isCleanText)

Comment: There is a `filter()` function, look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `NSCharacterSet` to hold your “dirty” characters:

```
let dirtyCharacters = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "~`!@#$%^&*()_+=-{}[]|;\'<>,./?1234567890")
```

Then you can detect the absence of any “dirty” character like this:

```
let isCleanText = randomText.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(dirtyCharacters) == nil
```

You can filter out all the “dirty” characters like this:

```
let cleanedText = randomText.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(dirtyCharacters)
    .joinWithSeparator("")
```

The [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/) is chock full of juicy morsels.